# How can a raid set be renamed

Tags: disk-utility, raid

I wasn't paying attention, and now I have a raid with a name similar to that of the boot partition.  I'd like to name rename the raid set to a name that reflects the partition name.  E.g. If the file system is mounted as /Users I want to name the raid set User_Raid

Now in normal circumstances the only time I have to worry about this is either using Disk Utility or diskutil.  But both commands are moderately complex, and the consequences of a mistake severe, so having a naming convention that makes it clear what disk is associated with what raid set and what file system helps a bunch.

[image]

Here's an example:  The raid set name is SSD_System,(Red annotations) which is the same as the boot disk (Green) and which is not the same as the raid's mount point which is User_Raid (Blue)

Is there a way to rename the raid set after creation?  (Yes I can change the boot disk name.  May do that yet.)

*(Note to the purists.  Raid is now a word like laser, and radar.  It has passed from being an acronym to being a word in it's own right.  Please do) not edit my post and convert raid to RAID.)*

Comment: Raid has always (OK, in the last 500 years) been a normal [word](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=raid&year_start=1500&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Craid%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Craid%3B%2Cc1) probably peeking 1942 due to the Doolittle Raid. I still prefer RAID ;-)

Comment: raid and RAID are two rather different things, see https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/raid

Comment: I can't immediately find a single document anywhere that calls it 'raid' rather than 'RAID', including Apple's own documentation, a Google search for 'raid storage', Wikipedia, and a handful of books on my shelf. So I'll certainly be sticking with RAID...

Comment: @klanomath The question is how to rename a RAID set, the mounting seems to be just an example.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the question. Won't disks (and RAIDs) always mount to the same location (/Volumes) automatically or am I mistaken?